# Does a third-party booking service know you've missed a flight?

Tags: bookings, airlines, missed-flights

Someone booked a ticket for me via a third-party company. Is there a way for the website to know I've missed the flight?

I guess my real question is: does anyone but the airline know I've missed the flight? Would the airline alert the booking company in any way?

Comment: Do you mean the 3rd party booking company knowing if you missed the flight - why would they care?  Or do you mean the person who made the booking knowing if you missed the flight they had (presumably) paid for?

Comment: Well, it might end up in the PNR, so "yes".  Or they might suspect you missed it and apply for a refund of fees.

Comment: @Nick I mean the 3rd party booking company knowing if I missed the flight. I guess my real question is: does anyone but the airline know if I've missed the flight? Would the airline alerted the booking company in any way?

Comment: @npl sorry, but what is the PNR?

Comment: @petim602 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_name_record  At least the German Wikipedia also lists "no shows" as information which is stored in the PNR

Comment: Do you mean know in **real time**?

Answer (score 1):

The [Passenger Name Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_name_record) lists all kind of information about your flight, and is also accessible to a travel agent.  One kind of information stored there is whether flights have been taken.  So, yes, the travel agent most likely can check whether you have taken a flight.

Comment: @TheZealot See the comment of the OP above: *"I mean the 3rd party booking company knowing if I missed the flight."*  What else would a "booking company" be?  In any case, the friend might equally learn this from the travel agent.